# Можно ли, отправить CURL запрос но указать там IP юзера а не сервера?

Tags: php, curl

Можно ли как-то отправить запрос через CURL php, и чтобы отправился IP юзера, а не IP сервера?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'site.ru/response.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Обычный запрос делаю, но CURL подставляет IP cервера с которого был запрос.

Заголовки запроса с файла response.php

```
[REMOTE_ADDR] => IP Сервера подставляется когда запрос CURL
```

А если я допустим через форму перейду или вручную по ссылке `site.ru/response.php`

Тогда такие заголовки запроса с файла response.php

```
[REMOTE_ADDR] => IP Пользователя
```

Так вот, можно ли в CURL подставить ип юзера так, чтобы на сервере в REMOTE_ADDR отображался ИП юзера?

Спасибо всем за ответы

Comment: Его разве что отправить данными можно.. Запрос не отправляется клиентом.. Клиент стучится на сервер и сервер уже отправляет запрос, напрямую сделать это нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Вы не сможете это сделать гораздо глубже: на уровне TCP протокола. Технически вы можете отправить TCP SYN пакет с поддельным адресом отправителя - на этом основан один из видов DDoS атак - но ответный пакет на предложение установить соединение сервер отправит на указанный в пакете IP адрес, а не вам. И установить TCP соединение таким образом будет невозможно. А без TCP соединения HTTP запрос не отправить, и, тем более, не получить на него ответ.

Если же оба сервера ваши - то вы можете передать необходимые данные например в дополнительных заголовках HTTP запроса. В частности через параметр `curl` `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` и получить их из `$_SERVER`.